# ActionBar title is not visible

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have implemented an actionbar but its title is not getting displayed. Also my app has two fragments , the title should change as per the fragment displayed.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

     AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;

     ViewPager mViewPager;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

       setupActionBar();

        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        // user swipes between sections.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onPageSelected(int position) 
            {
            }

            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) 
            {

            }

            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) 
            {
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)
                {

                }
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                {

                }
            }
        });


    }


    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {



        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:


                    return new AllPatient();

               case 1:

                    //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,abc.class);
                     return new LaunchpadSectionFragment();



            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;

        }



    }




    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        //actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);


       actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));

       actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
                ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
       ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup)LayoutInflater.from(this)
               .inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(v,
                new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT));
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(getTitle());

    } 


}
```

Please also tell me how to add dividers between the icons in actionbar.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried with Color.BLACK?

Comment: Yes i did. But nothing happened.

Comment: remove the actionBar.setCustomView call and check if it does any difference

Comment: Then i can see the title but the icons are not getting displayed. Only the logo and title is displaying.

Comment: for the logo you have to call setIcon

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this line:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

By this one:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Comment: Thanx but only logo and title is getting displayed not the icons.

Comment: Can you have a try with this instead?: `actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)`?

Comment: Nopes, title is not getting displayed. Thnx

Comment: Sorry, I think the solution is here but this function is not detailed at all in the documentation. You can have a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayOptions(int, int)

Answer (score 3):

Add the show title flag like so

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're adding a custom view with a width of MATCH_PARENT and Android removes the action bar title (but not the home icon) in that case. It's not very logical, but that's the behavior I see in my app. Setting the width to WRAP_CONTENT creates the same problem. The solution is to give the custom view a fixed width, or if you need the width to vary from one activity to another, calculate the width programmatically and set it to a new fixed width for each activity.

Answer (score 1):

This should definitely work

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);